# Proving well formed propositional statements have well defined truth values

Tags: induction, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to prove by induction that "Any well-formed propositional statement has a well-defined truth value.

The issue is that this seems like a rather mushy thing to prove, so I would also like clarification on what "well-defined means". My intuitive grasp doesn't mesh with the definition (if you can call it that) given in my text:

> "In mathematics, when you ask whether something is “well-deﬁned”, you mean that somewhere in the deﬁnition a choice was made, and you want to know whether a diﬀerent choice would have resulted in the same ﬁnal result. For example, let $X_1 = ({−2,2})$ and let $X_2 = ({−1,2})$. Deﬁne $y_1$ by: “Choose x in X1 and let $y_1 = x^2.”$ Deﬁne $y_2$ by: “Choose x in $X_2$ and let $y_2 = x^2.”$ Then y1 is well-deﬁned, and is the number 4; but $y_2$ is not well-deﬁned, as diﬀerent choices of x give rise to diﬀerent numbers."

My understanding of well-defined seems to be pretty mushy, and seems to be basically injectivity: that a choice of element in the range should have an unambiguous inverse image. I know this isn't quite right, but the above example doesn't help; it seems like $y_2$ *is* well defined, because you know exactly which element of $X_2$ it comes from. If someone could help me untangle these ideas, it would be helpful.

Here is my attempt at a proof of the proposition above:

Consider a well-formed statement P with definite truth value $a|a\in{0, 1}$. Such a statement clearly exists ("I have a nose", for example).

Now consider a compound statement $Q = Q_1 c_1 Q_2 c_2...Q_n$ where $Q_i$ is a well formed statement, as above, and $c_i$ is a connective with a prescribed truth value. Assume Q has a well defined truth value.

Let $Q' =  Q_1 c_1 Q_2 c_2...Q_n c_n Q_{n+1} = Qc_nQ_{n+1}$ Because $Q$ and $Q_{n+1}$ have well defined truth values, and the connective $c_n$ does, so too does $Q'$. Thus, by induction, the proposition is true for all well-formed propositional statements.

Any feedback or clarification of any of the above would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is the basic idea.  The process you go through is called structural induction, as you exploit the way how propositions are recursively defined to show that they indeed do all have exactly one truth-value.

Comment: Great, good to know. Any chance you feel like taking a crack at my confusion regarding 'well-defined'?

Comment: Ok, 'well-defined' does not mean injectivity, but is closer to 'functionality': the definition tells us exactly what the one and only one thing, that is being defined, is. E.g. If I define x to be 'the whole number smaller than 7', we would not consider that well-defined,since there are still many options for what x could be. But if I define it to be 'the whole number smaller than 7 but larger than 5', then it is well-defined, since there is exactly one such number. In the case of your propositions, you need to show that the definition is such that each statement has exactly one truth-value.

Comment: Ah; but it doesn't seem like I've done that. And I'm not certain how I would without making some statement about the well-definedness of the operations of propositional calculus as a system.

Comment: I think you basically have!  You show (base of induction) )that every atomic statement has exactly one truth-value (for this you will need to consult the definition of an atomic statement), and then (inductive step) you show that, assuming (inductive hypothesis) P and Q have a definite truth-value (where P and Q are any statements, atomic or not), the statement P * Q has a definite truth-value as well, where * is any of the operators used (so here use the truth-functional definition of all operators used). (If you have operators with more than two arguments, generalize to those as well)

Comment: So what I am saying is: you really have the right 'proof skeleton'. You just need to clean it up a bit, and yes, explicitly refer to how atomic statements and the operators used in your system are defined.

Answer (score 1):

'Well-defined' has nothing to do with injectivity; that is where you are confused. 'Well-defined' in this context simply means that every proposition has exactly one truth-value. To show this, you show:

Base: ever atomic proposition has exactly one truth-value (refer to definition of atomic statements and their truth-values here)

Step: Any complex statement that is the result of applying some logical operator to a bunch of other statements has exactly one truth-value assuming (hypothesis) those other statements have exactly one truth-value (refer to truth-functional nature of each defined operator here).

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

So what does this question mean?

Suppose $Q =Q_1c_1Q_2c_2 \ldots c_n Q_n$ is a compound statement. To find its truth value we inductively find the truth value of each $Q_i$ (eventually this will reduce to checking atomic statements which obviously have well-defined truth-values) and then determine the truth value of $Q$ as the connectives $c_i$ dictate. For example if $c= \wedge$ gives $Q_1 c Q_2$ true iff both $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are true.

To show this procedure always gives the same answer we must consider alternate expressions $Q = Q_1'c_1'Q_2'c_2' \ldots c_m' Q_m'$, apply the above algorithm to the new expression, and prove the answer is the same.

For example $(\neg A) \wedge B \wedge C$ is the same as $(\neg A) \wedge( B \wedge C)$.

Comment: Right, this is what I was afraid this would entail; I guess I know intuitively this is true, but it's difficult to see a strategy for actually writing down a proof that doesn't come down to an endless string of cases. Generally when I find myself doing that sort of thing it means that my global view of the problem isn't very clear. Any tips on how I would organize such a thing?

Comment: Since some of the definitions of formal logic use induction, it is natural the proofs do the same, even if it seems a bit strange. As to making your proof, does disjunctive normal form mean anything to you?

Comment: It does now that I've googled it, but my familiarity with Boolean Algebra is not such that I was able to make much of the definition.