# How does a propositional formula represents a $n$-ary function?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am reading Wolfgang Rautenberg's introduction to logic, in page 9 he proves that given a propositional formula $a$ with at most the variables $p_1,...,p_n$ for all valuations $w, w'$
$$wa = w'a \text{ whenever } wp_i = w'p_i \text{ for } i=1,...,n.$$
He then says that $a$ represents only one $n$-ary function, $f$, due to the last proposition according to the following:
$$
wa = f(wp_1,wp_2,...,wp_n) \text{ for all valuations }w.
$$
In my understanding he is defining a map from the set of formulas with at most $n$ variables to the set of $n$-ary functions however I can't figure out how one would prove this map is well defined using the propostition. I found this post [Proving well formed propositional statements have well defined truth values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011969/proving-well-formed-propositional-statements-have-well-defined-truth-values) which seems to be similar to my question but I couldn't extrapolate a solution to my case.
So how can we prove that such map is well defined? Plus why would we need such a propostion? It seems to me that it doesn't add significant information.

Comment: Maybe induction on the number of connectives/the formation tree of the formula...

Comment: Intuitively, a [Truth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_function) is a function whose output (a truth value) depends **only** on the truth-values of the input (the arguments).

Comment: Yes I know that and intuitively I even know to what function a propositional formula $a$ maps to. But I wanted to know the proof that it maps to only one function.

Comment: Truth table of the formula: it is the "description" of the truth-function corresponding to the formula. $p \land q$ will output T exactly when both inputs $p,q$ have value T.

Comment: The author **proves** that for every formula $\alpha$, two valuations matching on the prop letters will produce the same truth value. Then he **defines** the truth function *representing* the formula. Having proved that the output of the "valuation process" is uniquely determined by the input, we know that the corresponding function is "well defined": a single output for each imput.

Comment: A sensible question about the significance of such a formula representation of a well defined Boolean function. Since this is only page 9 of your book and I never read this book so maybe after you finish more reading you can come back to answer yourself. From my reading of your question, there may be multiple or even infinite number of different looking representations for such a truth function, but they're all isomorphic up to logical equivalence. So each f is essentially an equivalence class of all formulas composed by $p_i$. Per unique inductive construction of formulas, f is well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lemma is crucial to interpret what Rautenberg says.

**Definition**. Suppose $w$ and $w'$ are valuations and $\alpha$ is a propositional formaula. We say $w$ and $w'$ agrees on $\alpha$ if for any propositional variable $p$ occurred in $\alpha$ we have $wp=w'p$.

**Lemma** (Agreement). For any valuations $w,w'$ and propositional formula $\alpha$, if  $w$ and $w'$ agree on $a$ then $w\alpha = w'\alpha$.

It can be proved by induction on formula $\alpha$. Agreement Lemma as above is similar to Agreement/Coincidence Lemma in first order logic, and in fact shows

$$
f(wp_1,wp_2,...,wp_n)=w\alpha
$$

is a map which is your confusion.